# After verbing ... that saw ... . Who saw?

Tags: relative-clauses

There is a sentense:

> Erdoğan reiterated a promise to continue a policy of repatriating Syrian refugees after riding a wave of hardline nationalist sentiment that saw the former ultranationalist presidential candidate Sinan Oğan joined him to declare victory in Ankara.

I copied this from the [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/may/29/turkish-lira-plunges-as-erdogan-claims-mandate-to-continue-divisive-rule#:%7E:text=Erdo%C4%9Fan%20reiterated%20a%20promise%20to%20continue%20a%20policy%20of%20repatriating%20Syrian%20refugees%20after%20riding%20a%20wave%20of%20hardline%20nationalist%20sentiment%20that%20saw%20the%20former%20ultranationalist%20presidential%20candidate%20Sinan%20O%C4%9Fan%20joined%20him%20to%20declare%20victory%20in%20Ankara.).

I feel it is weird as there is **after verbing ... that saw ...** .  Who saw?

---

As someone state that the **that** clause refers to **a wave of**, so if we make **that** refers to **sentiment**, how should we write this sentence. From these, I can tell under what conditions, what **that** refers to.

Comment: "Saw" can mean "lead to". The sentence is a bit of a mouthful, and "joined" is a typo (should be "join"), but it looks like it was the **wave** that saw / lead to Sinan joining him.

Comment: @ralph.m  But shouldn't **that** refer to the thing just before it? So, does **that** refer to **sentiment**?

Comment: @ralph.m - I think you meant that **saw** (past tense) can mean **led** to (past tense).

Comment: "joined" is wrong, it should be "join". However it is wrong in the source too: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/may/29/turkish-lira-plunges-as-erdogan-claims-mandate-to-continue-divisive-rule#:~:text=Erdo%C4%9Fan%20reiterated%20a%20promise%20to%20continue%20a%20policy%20of%20repatriating%20Syrian%20refugees%20after%20riding%20a%20wave%20of%20hardline%20nationalist%20sentiment%20that%20saw%20the%20former%20ultranationalist%20presidential%20candidate%20Sinan%20O%C4%9Fan%20joined%20him%20to%20declare%20victory%20in%20Ankara.

Comment: You should include the link to the source in your answer.  You aren't a new contributor and should know better.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey — Yes, definitely "led". Sloppy typo!

Comment: @Y.zeng — Well, yes, but the subject really is "a wave of hardline nationalist sentiment", but I'd say with "wave" as the "head".

Comment: @ralph.m If the author wanted to the **head** to be **sentiment**, what would be he/she should write?

Comment: @Y.zeng — I'm not sure it's really practical without completely rewriting the sentence.

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary? I looked at [M-W's entry for the verb "to see"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see) and found the answer very quickly.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I can't find the meaning of **lead to** from the site you posted.

Comment: @ralph.m If you can rewrite the sentence, how should you write to make **head** to be **sentiment**?

Comment: @Y.zeng I won't answer in comments, since doing so is frowned upon. If you edit your question to describe the reasonable research that you did (what you found and why you still have doubts), then I'll be glad to post an actual answer.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan  Okay. I have modified my question. I hope it meet your request.

Answer (score 1):

This is newspaper-speak, which isn't quite like normal English. Unfortunately, reporters have become influenced by "headlinese", which has a number of idioms originally intended to cut down the number of words so as to fit the space better; over the years many of these have made their way into the body copy itself, where they don't really belong.

So, "after" is frequently used to join together two related events even if they don't follow directly on from each other.

And "saw" is a shorthand way of saying "caused" or "led to".

But note that you're not quite parsing this correctly; it wasn't the "riding" that "saw" anything, it was the "wave of nationalist sentiment":

> Erdoğan reiterated a promise to continue a policy of repatriating Syrian refugees. He rode a wave of hardline nationalist sentiment [to win the election].
>
> [Thanks to/because of this,] the former ultranationalist presidential candidate Sinan Oğan joined him to declare victory in Ankara.

Comment: I often see 'see' used to mean that something happened during some period, e.g. Franklin Roosevelt's presidency (or 'the 1930s')  saw a number of series of programs, public work projects, financial reforms, and regulations which addressed problems caused by the Depression.